# How to securely store database credentials in a Spring MVC web application?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have a Spring MVC web application which needs to connect to a database, and the data source credentials are currently (in development) being kept in the application context configuration file, i.e. in WEB-INF\spring\application_context.xml like so:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="username" value="my_username" />
    <property name="password" value="my_password" />
    <property name="url" value="my_datasource_url" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
</bean>
```

Before I deploy this application to a public facing Tomcat server I want to make sure that I'm not making these database credentials visible to the world or easily discovered by a crafty hacker.  Am I OK keeping things as they are, i.e. in plain text and in an XML file under WEB-INF?  If not then is there a best practice for this sort of thing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another thing to consider would be to have a JNDI lookup.  JNDI would be contained within the servlet container (tomcat in your case) allowing connections to the database only through webapps currently deployed from Tomcat.

This way also creates a silo'd experience between build management and development so development doesn't have the keys to the car, if you get my metaphor.

Comment: If the WEB-INF directory where I'm keeping my database credentials is invisible to the outside then it sounds like that's as secure as I can hope for.  I's not clear why I'd want to move from keeping the credentials there to using a JNDI approach which appears to be more convoluted and requires more configuration/maintenance.  Can any give good reasons why I'd go this JNDI route over the simpler approach which is working fine and which doesn't seem to be insecure?

Comment: With JNDI, the control can be out of your hands, allowing for separation of concerns while deploying.  The build management team would handle the credentials and supply the development team with an endpoint for which to connect.  It's usually for bigger projects in which credentials poses security risk for employees, etc. It's also nice for maintenance for the developer cause the endpoint won't change if the datasource jndi name stays the same, even if it's a new database, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Dardo; this is the way I ended up going and it's working well.

Comment: Not a problem, happy to help =)

Answer (score 5):

Files stored in `WEB-INF` folder are by definition inaccessible from the outside world. E.g. if you put JSP file there no user can access that file directly - it can be referenced for example by importing or including from another JSP.

That being said your credentials are safe, but it is not a good practice to hard code them in the `applicationContext.xml`. Are you pushing these credentials to your source control?

The safest way is to extract sensitive and frequently changing configuration in an external `.properties` file somewhere on your hard disk. Spring is perfectly capable of reading `.properties` files.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification, Tomasz.  I'm already reading the credentials from a .properties file, but that file is in the same directory under WEB-INF as is the application context configuration XML file.  If the WEB-INF directory is locked to outside users then how is it that a location outside of the WEB-INF is a more secure place from which to store/read .properties files?  I guess one reason is that you never include the user/pass in the WAR using that approach (i.e. the .properties file containing the database credentials is always on disk rather than included in the WAR).  Any others?

Answer (score 1):

You could make it ask the password on startup. But usually what i see is passwords in xml files which are chmodded and chowned to be only accessible by the web software itself. There are no easy good solutions.

One basic step is to make sure that the tomcat-user has only the access it needs on the database , so if it is compromised, the damage is limited.